# awk gsub in $0 changes variable as well

Tags: variables, awk, gsub

I am trying to assign the text coming in to awk to a variable, then change $0 and then output the original and the changed string:

```
# echo "This is a test" |awk '{text=$0; gsub(/ /,"%20"); print $text; print $0;}' 
This%20is%20a%20test
This%20is%20a%20test
```

But I am expecting that to return

```
This%20is%20a%20test
This is a test
```

Trying to change the #text variables does the same thing.

```
# echo "This is a test" |awk '{text=$0; $text gsub(/ /,"%20"); print $text; print $0;}' 
This%20is%20a%20test
This%20is%20a%20test
```

GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.3, GNU MP 6.0.0) on a Synology running DSM 6.2

Comment: I don't think your first example is doing what you think it is doing. Try copying the command line you included from your question and into a shell, and you'll see what I mean. Then try the same command line with the dollar sign removed from `print $text`, and let us know your results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's analyze your original code-line :

```
awk '{text=$0; gsub(/ /,"%20"); print $text; print $0;}'
```

- `text=$0`: very simple you store the current record in the variable `text`
- `gsub(/ /,"%20")` : this replaces all spaces with `%20` in the string `$0`. This is according to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

  > `gsub(ere, repl[, in])`
  >   Behave like `sub`, except that it shall replace all occurrences of the regular expression `ere` in `$0` or in the `in` argument, when specified.

  It should be understood that this substitution is *inplace*. Therefore `$0` is now updated and different from `text`.
- `print $text` : Here is the culprit, you wish to do `print text` but you wrote `$text`. The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) states :

  > Field variables shall be designated by a `$` followed by a number or numerical expression.

  as you wrote `$text` and `text` is currently a string, it will try to convert the string to a number as it expects one. As it fails, the conversion returns `ZERO` and this at this point `$text` is equivalent to `$0` which represents the current record (which you previously updated with `gsub`).
- `print $0`: here you print the current record.

In conclusion:

If you expect the following output :

```
This%20is%20a%20test
This is a test
```

The the following two `awk` lines give this :

```
awk '{text=$0; gsub(/ /,"%20",text); print text; print $0)'
awk '{text=$0; gsub(/ /,"%20"); print $0; print text }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following may help you here. In `awk` `$` means a specific field's value it doesn't work like shell.

```
echo "This is a test" | awk '{val=$0;gsub(/ /,"%20",val);print val ORS $0}'
This%20is%20a%20test
This is a test
```

Comment: In gawk, one might even do this without a variable: `gawk '{print gensub(/ /,"%20","g",$0) ORS $0}' <<<"This is a test"`